# How specify rectangle size in Sonnet lite

Tags: microstrip, em

Although not directly an electronics question, there is probably someone who can help me out.
I just started to use Sonnet lite to simulate a microstrip filter. There is one aspect, which to me seems very basic and which I am unable to do. Looked into the help file, but also couldn't get a clear answer.

I have a calculated geometry (only rectangular elements) for a filter, and want to draw this geometry in Sonnet. I just want to specify width and height of the rectangles, but it seems impossible. When drawing a rectangle and select 'resize' I only can select a percentage for resizing.

I cannot believe that the only way to get a rectangle at the desired size, is dragging with the mouse.

Am I overlooking something here ?